# Using `$utils.defaultIfNullOrEmpty` to save Boolean Value

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, aws-amplify-cli

When the user does not send `$context.arguments.input.isActive` I replace this `null` value to a default one, like this:

`#set($isActive = $utils.defaultIfNullOrEmpty($context.arguments.input.isActive, true))`

But for some reason, this `isActive` is saved as `null`.

For example:

I have defined in the `schema.graphql` this mutation:

```
type Mutation {
  updateAccount(input: AccountInput!): Boolean
    @aws_auth(cognito_groups: ["SuperAdmin"])
}

input AccountInput {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  picture: String!
  isActive: Boolean
}
```

So, when the user does not send the `isActive`, like this:

```
mutation {
  updateAccount(input: {
    id: "xxxxx"
    name: "xxxxx"
    picture: "public/xxxxx/xxxxxx.jpg"
  })
}
```

The `isActive` value is saved as `null`. And should be saved as `true`

Here's the complete code of the Resolver of `updateAccount`:

```
#set($id = $context.arguments.input.id)
#set($currentDate = $utils.time.nowISO8601())

#set($isActive = $utils.defaultIfNullOrEmpty($context.arguments.input.isActive, true))

{
  "version": "2018-05-29",
  "operation": "UpdateItem",
  "key": {
    "id": $utils.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($id)
  },
  "update": {
    "expression": "SET #name = :name, #picture = :picture, #isActive = :isActive, #updatedAt = :updatedAt",
    "expressionNames": {
      "#name": "name",
      "#picture": "picture",
      "#isActive": "isActive",
      "#updatedAt": "updatedAt"
    },
    "expressionValues": {
      ":name": $utils.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($context.arguments.input.name),
      ":picture": $utils.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($context.arguments.input.picture),
      ":isActive": $utils.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($isActive),
      ":updatedAt": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($currentDate)
    }
  },
  "condition": {
    "expression": "attribute_exists(id)"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I could fix it like this:

```
#set($isActive = true)

#if(!$utils.isNull($context.arguments.input.isActive))
  #set($isActive = $context.arguments.input.isActive)
#end
```

But why:

```
#set($isActive = $utils.defaultIfNullOrEmpty($context.arguments.input.isActive, true))
```

does not work for me?